# how to run a query in looping in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

im sory, im noob in laravel. later, im build web just use php native, and i have code like this

```
$query1 = select * from user where id='$id';

while($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1){

     $query2 = select * from komen where iduser=$data['id'];

}
```

so to convert to laravel be what. 
I already read the documentation laravel but did not find

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Where `id = $id` should only return 1 value (given that id is your unique primary key), so you would never have to loop through the result of your `$query1`, it's just 1 or nothing.

Best thing you can do to fetch the related Komen is to setup a relation in the model. For more info see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Best option for you is to create the User model first (already exists after Laravel installation) and add the komens() relation (1:n)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user'; // should be users

    // define has many relationship
    public function komens()
    {
        //  you will have to set userid, as laravel searches for user_id (singular tablename _ key)
        return $this->hasMany(Komen::class, 'userid');
    }
}
```

Then create the Komen model (check your naming conventions, laravel looks for the table name as the lowercase snake_cased plural version of your model name, so in this case `komens`. If you want to overwrite this, you have to set the `protected $table = 'komen';`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Komen extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'komen'; // should be komens

    // define the inverse of the user model's komens() method
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userid');
    }
}
```

Now in your code you can do something like this:

```
// fetch the user by id
$user = User::find($id);
// check if user exists
if ($user) {
    // fetch all related komens from the database and loop through the collection
    $user->komens->each(function($komen) {
        // do foo here
        dump($komen);
    });
}
```

Check out the Eloquent ORM documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: This is by far the most correct answer to the question because this is the 'Laravel' way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First create the UserModel and KomenModel.
then use this

```
$queryData = UserModel::find($id);
foreach ($queryData as $data) {
   $query2 = KomenModel::find($data->id);

}
```

or instead of above code you can do this using laravel join query.

Comment: `$queryData` would be an instance of the user model instead of a collection to loop through.  This should really be done with relationships though instead of a join query.  These kind of loops are dangerous because they easily create an N+1 issue.

Comment: Yes, above we have also mainsion  about relationship

Answer (score 0):

There are two way of creating Queries...

1.Query...using normal  DB::table...

2.Eloquent Model...

description
1.

```
`$data = DB::table('Tablname')->where('id',$id)->all();`
```

in here USE DB;
and there are severl methods such as all() , get()

2.

```
$this->model->where($attrib, '=', $value)->get();
```

where we go from the model option...

But as i understood you can go with DB query method..

```
$result= DB::table('komen')->where('id', $id)->all();

//check the previous query have got any data...
if($result)
{
   //go for the second Query.....
}
```

If there is any need just mention...I am also new to laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

You can get by following code without use any model.

```
$Data = DB::table('user')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
foreach ($Data as $data) {
   $query2 = DB::table('komen')->where('iduser', '=', $data->id)->get();
}
```